# Table View Insert error

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

Hi guys i get this error when i try to add to a empty table view : insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update. Any thoughts?

```
  dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Blog Fetcher", NULL);
  dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
                      //pull this call out to Blog+twitter later saving should only take 
                      //place in the model!

                        [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^
                        {
                            NSArray* resultsArray = [self.tweets objectForKey:@"results"]; 

                            for (NSDictionary* internalDict in resultsArray)
                            {

                            User *user = [NSEntityDescription 
                                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
                                user.username =[internalDict objectForKey:@"from_user_name"];
                                [self.context save:nil];

                                self.list = [self.list arrayByAddingObject:user];
                                NSLog(@" indexpath set here %i",self.list.count-1);
                                NSIndexPath *newIndexpath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.list.count-1  inSection:0];
                                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            }
                        }];

              });
            dispatch_release(fetchQ);

}
```

Comment: As @JefferyThomas implies, all updates to UIKit objects (such as a tableview) must be done from the main thread.  Also, make sure that all of your core data save's are being done on the same thread (don't do it on the main thread **and** this thread!).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you should dispatch updates to the main thread. I'm not sure about your implementation details, but you may also need to move `[self.context save:nil]` to the main thread also.

```
NSArray* resultsArray = [self.tweets objectForKey:@"results"];
NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:resultsArray.count];
NSMutableArray *indexPaths =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:resultsArray.count];
NSInteger row = self.list.count;

for (NSDictionary* internalDict in resultsArray)
{
    User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    user.username =[internalDict objectForKey:@"from_user_name"];
    [self.context save:nil];

    [users addObject:user];

    NSLog(@" indexpath set here %i", row);
    NSIndexPath *newIndexpath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    row++;

    [indexPaths addObject:newIndexpath];
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.list = [self.list arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:users];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
};
```